# How to find the path between 2 nodes in a tree?

Tags: java, graph, tree, depth-first-search

I am trying to find the path between 2 nodes of a tree using java but i'm getting wrong answer

'''

```
public static void dfs(int source ,int destination ,ArrayList<Integer> path ,ArrayList<Integer> graph[] ,boolean vis[]){
    path.add(x);
    if(source == destination)
    return ;
    vis[source] = true;
    flag = 0;
    if(graph[source].size()!=0){
        for (int j : graph[source]){
            if(vis[j] == false){
                dfs(j,destination,path,graph,vis)
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag == 0){
        path.remove(path.size()-1);
    }
}
```

'''

for a tree of 11 nodes whose edges are given 
1 2 
2 3 
2 4 
2 8 
4 5 
4 6 
4 7 
8 9 
8 10 
8 11 
the path between node 1 and 8 should be : 1->2->8 but with this code , the result comes out to be 1->2->4->8 
Similarly , the path between node 3 and 6 should be : 3->2->4->6 , but this code yields the output : 3->2->4->6->8.
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

You do have some variables not declared in `dfs` method. Especially in the recursive calls, you need to be careful what should be declared as a local variable, what should be passed through parameters, and what can be declared as a global static variable.

Your back-tracking implementation of `dfs` is not correct. You accumulate all the nodes that you have traversed in the `path`, not the path to the target.

You need to re-design your code. For instance, instead of returning void, your function may return a boolean whether search is succeeded. Then you may decide not to alter `path` anymore. Alternatively, your function may return the `path` to target.

A better implementation for that `dfs` could be:

```
public static boolean dfs(int source, int destination, 
                          List<Integer> path, 
                          List<Integer> graph[], 
                          boolean vis[]) {
    path.add(source);
    if (source == destination) {
        return true;
    }
    vis[source] = true;
    if (!graph[source].isEmpty()) {
        for (int j : graph[source]) {
            if (!vis[j]) {
                if (dfs(j, destination, path, graph, vis)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    path.remove(path.size() - 1);
    return false;
}
```